Type C Schengen Visa - Amsterdam
I have to apply for a Type C Schengen Visa for business purposes. In my invitation letter is stated the dates that I will be in the Netherlands.
My question, can I apply for the Schengen Visa to arrive to Amsterdam 2 to 3 weeks earlier for travel/tourism purpose? Do I have to add other documents to my application?

This question is similar to: Schengen visa for leisure purposes after attending a conference. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If this is your first Schengen visa application, I would strongly recommend you keep things as simple as possible.

A consular officer will probably see 2 to 3 weeks as enough to change the purpose of your trip from mainly business to being at least a combination, and that also changes the documentation required.

Yes, but it may be more difficult.
A Schengen C visa allows you to mix business and tourism. It is entirely normal to add a few days of sightseeing to a business trip, or to recuperate from an exhausting flight before the business starts.
In your application you would write that the main purpose of your trip is business, and document that. Even if you spend more days on tourism than on business, you need to apply at the consulate for your business destination. (Example: You have one day of business meetings in Amsterdam. You plan to fly to Paris and see the sights the weekend before. One visa application, made with the Netherlands and not France.)
The problem:

In a visa application for tourism, you usually have to explain that you have a stable, well-paid job and that your employer does not object to a lengthy vacation. In a visa application for business, you have to explain that you have business in Europe.
Now you have to explain both.
In a visa application for tourism, you have to explain that your savings and income are enough to afford the trip. In a visa application for business, you have to explain that there is a business which pays for your travel to Europe.
Now you have to explain both.

In your application, you will have to make clear who pays what, and why. If your employer pays for the flight, the employer needs to make it clear that they agree with flying early, and with taking the vacation before the business meeting. If you are funding the extension of the stay, you need to show where the money for the hotels comes from.
With visa applications, "normal" is "good." If your arrangements confuse the visa officials, they may deny it. So take extra care to be clear.

Also note that while the official application form allows you to check multiple reasons, some of the processors’ online forms do not.
